# How to capture FIO (Flexible IO) status message using popen in C++

Tags: c++

When I run fio in linux shell, 
the fio will display process status while it running.

```
fio_common: (g=0): rw=write, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
fio-2.2.10
Starting 1 process
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)] [4.9% done] [0KB/197.9MB/0KB /s] [0/50.7K/0 iops] [eta 00m
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)] [6.6% done] [0KB/209.8MB/0KB /s] [0/53.6K/0 iops] [eta 00m
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)] [8.2% done] [0KB/50696KB/0KB /s] [0/12.7K/0 iops] [eta 00m
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)] [9.8% done] [0KB/209.1MB/0KB /s] [0/53.6K/0 iops] [eta 00m
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)] [11.5% done] [0KB/208.1MB/0KB /s] [0/53.5K/0 iops] [eta 00
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)] [13.1% done] [0KB/51556KB/0KB /s] [0/12.9K/0 iops] [eta 00
....
```

And display result after test

```
fio_common: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=17635: Thu Oct  8 16:04:10 2015
  write: io=3194.8MB, bw=327040KB/s, iops=81760, runt= 10001msec
    slat (usec): min=2, max=3371, avg= 4.44, stdev= 5.13
    clat (usec): min=40, max=3764, avg=380.23, stdev=57.12
     lat (usec): min=45, max=3772, avg=386.59, stdev=57.59
    clat percentiles (usec):
     | 99.000th=[  454], 99.900th=[ 1080], 99.990th=[ 2960], 99.999th=[ 3760],
     | 100.000th=[ 3760]
    bw (KB  /s): min=314728, max=361528, per=100.00%, avg=327430.74, stdev=17662.04
    lat (usec) : 50=0.01%, 100=0.01%, 250=0.01%, 500=99.52%, 750=0.34%
    lat (usec) : 1000=0.02%
    lat (msec) : 2=0.10%, 4=0.02%
  cpu          : usr=10.84%, sys=88.64%, ctx=949, majf=0, minf=13
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=100.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=0/w=817682/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0, drop=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: io=3194.8MB, aggrb=327040KB/s, minb=327040KB/s, maxb=327040KB/s, mint=10001msec, maxt=10001msec

Disk stats (read/write):
  sdc: ios=91/809830, merge=0/0, ticks=8/33252, in_queue=33080, util=99.09%
```

Now, I want to using popen() to execute Flexible IO in C++.

My method is as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE *fioProcess;
char *fioCommand = "sudo fio myJob";
char msgBuf[4096];
int  readLength;

fioProcess = popen(fioCommand, "r");
if(fioProcess)
{
    while(!feof(fioProcess))
    {
        readLength = fread(msgBuf, sizeof(char), sizeof(msgBuf), fioProcess);
        if(readLength > 0)
        {                
            //parsing msgBuf...
            //...
            //...
        }
        sleep(100);            
    }
}
```

but I can only capture the result after test. 
there are no any process status information I can get by fread() or fget() while fio running.
How to capture fio process status message using popen in C++?

Comment: What `popen` does is forking a new process and set up a pipe that the parent process can read from while the child process executes the program. You can do this manually, and let the child process just run along until it finishes and read in parallel from the pipe in the parent process. System calls to look up: [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [`dup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) and [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html).

Comment: Also, there are many example all over the Internet if you just search a little.